# Is it possible to switch git branch and untracked the files rather than removing it?

Tags: git

Upon switching branch, let say `feature2` to `feature1`. For each files not in `feature2` but in `feature1`, by default git will remove all the file not in `feature2` upon `checkout` into the branch. Is it possible to untrack the file instead of removing it.

I am switching between branches. These files are being removed when I'm in another branch. I still need these files for my app to run. I have gitignore those files on both branch, but on one side of the branch, I force to track them.

Comment: would `git reset --soft feature1` work? You would have to backup feature2 with `checkout -b backup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` in sparse mode to pull down changes.

If there are one or two files, try

```
git checkout feature2 -- <filenames>
```

If there are lots and lots of files, try

```
git checkout feature2 -- .
git checkout feature1 -- .
```

The first pulls in files from *feature2* into your working directory, while the second will pull *ALL* of *feature2* into the your working directory, then pulls *feature1* back over the top, effectively merging the contents of the two branches.

By default, the files checked out this way are added to the index. (`git status` will show them as ready to commit).

You should `git reset -- .` to unstage them.

Answer (score -1):

You can stash the changes before switching branches by using `git stash -u` (-u will stash untracked files as well). Stashing will undo all changes and store them in a temporary commit that can be applied any time later.

When you want the files to exist again you can run `git stash pop`